# How to get the index of the input radio selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to get the index of the selected input radio when click a button. so, I use click function.

```
$('id').click(function(){
    $('input[name="name"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked') === 'checked'){
            ...
        }
    })
})
```

But I found that the checked property of the input radio does not change, actually there is no 'checked' attr at all on the dom node.

So, do I have to set the 'checked' prop on the input radio before read it via $.change() method? if not, then, how to get the index of the input radio that has been selected.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not asking the code to replace the ... part, I am saying that the if condition wont work as there is no prop [checked] at all on the input node after selected.

Comment: As an aside `$(this).prop('checked')` is a boolean, so you shouldn't need the `=== 'checked'` if you were to use a conditional.

Comment: Thanks, now I know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
var index = $("input[name=radio]:checked").index();
$('#span').html(index)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='button' value='click' id='btn'>
<span id='span'></span>
```

Try like this

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function you can grab the index of each element.

Using the [`.is(':checked')`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) function you can check if something is checked.

Mix these together and you can try something like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i,o){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert(i);
});
```

[**CHECK OUT THIS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/w18eqg5y/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript version using `findIndex`:

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
   var index = [... document.querySelectorAll("input[name=radio]")].findIndex(e=>e.checked)
   span.innerHTML = index;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='radio' name='radio'>
<input type='button' value='get index' id='btn'>
<span id='span'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need.

```
var index = $('input[name="name"]:checked').index();
```